# Restart a bunch of servers, keeping only a few down during the restart

Tags: bash

Consider the following script:

```
for host in $(get-all-hosts)
do
  (restart-server $host; wait-for-server-to-come-up $host) &
done
```

As you might guess, `restart-server` restarts the server and the command `wait-for-server-to-come-up` blocks until the server is up (e.g., `grep -m 1 'server up' <(tail -f /path/to/log)`).

This script essentially restarts all servers simultaneously. I'm curious what's the simplest way to modify this script to stop after some fixed number of servers, and wait for one server to come up before proceeding with the next restart so that a maximum of, say, 4 servers is down at any given time. One way I know of doing this is to simply restart in chunks of 4 and wait on all of the pids in each chunk, but I'm hoping it's not that hard to do something smarter.

Some scratch work toward a solution:

Second try, using some ideas from Dennis's link. Almost ideal for a vanilla Bash solution:

```
mkfifo mfifo
exec 3<>mfifo
echo >&3
echo >&3
echo >&3
for host in $(get-all-hosts)
do
  read
  (restart-server $host; wait-for-server-to-come-up $host; echo >&3) &
done <&3
```

My biggest remaining complaint with this solution is that it assumes there isn't already a named queue called mfifo that's already in use. Other than that, I haven't seen any problems, and it works exactly as expected as far as I can tell.

Comment: Add a counter of down hosts and an inner while loop. While servers down > x, sample down hosts until servers down < x. Each time a server goes down, increment x, when one comes up decrement x.

Comment: How do you decrement? I just tried it and it seems like the counter never decrements, perhaps because these are running in separate processes.

Comment: Can the while loop solution be executed by reading from a file descriptor that the subprocess writes to, perhaps?

Comment: Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement).

Comment: Regarding the fifo, you can do `fifodir=$(mktemp -d -t fifodir.XXXXXXXXX); mkfifo "$fifodir/fifo"`. Just remember to `trap 'rm -rf "$fifodir"' EXIT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xargs` has a parallelism feature similar to `parallel`:

```
echo $(get-all-hosts) | tr ' ' '\n' | xargs -P 4 -n 1 ./blocking-restart
```

..where `blocking-restart` is expected to take the name of a single server, restart it and wait until it's finished.  Note the `tr` puts each host on its own line, which is what xargs expects.

Answer (score 1):

The `parallel` tool (in the Ubuntu / Debian `moreutils` package) may be able to help here; if you re-write the `restart-server` tool to block until the server comes back up, you could run the scripts in a manner like this:

```
parallel -j 4 restart-server -- $(get-all-hosts)
```

Of course, if four servers don't come back up, the whole thing grinds to a halt. Perhaps that's desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I am interested in how to do this with a simple Bash script still using only basics, since this would increase my general understanding of what's achievable in Bash/Unix.